# Проблема с Sprite Editor в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

К сожалению, я не могу кинуть видео, но постараюсь описать проблему в скрирншоте.
Когда я их заедитил и хочу сделать например Player_idle.anim, то даже при одиннаковой высоте и ширине, один из кадров дергается, из-за этого не получается нормально создать анимацию стоящего.
Надеюсь нормально объяснил
[image: Скрины]

Comment: https://vimeo.com/user118495111/review/433036156/245eef9ce4

Comment: Вообщем, если кого-то интересует фикс проблемы, нужно научится нормально ставить Pivot points, попбробуйте в использовании TexturePacker, очень удобный